# Check time range in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

We have Pandas dataframe with start_date and end_date columns(Input format is given below). I need to check whether the given input time range is present between the start_date and end_date.

For example, if the time range is 09:30-10:30, the output should be first row (student1) and if time range is 16:00-17:30, the output should be second row (student2). Please guide me how can I achieve this.

**Input Dataframe:**

```
        name          start_date            end_date
0   student1    2020-08-30 09:00:00     2020-08-30 10:00:00
1   student2    2020-08-30 15:00:00     2020-08-30 18:00:00
2   student3    2020-08-30 11:00:00     2020-08-30 12:30:00
```

Answer (score 1):

Supposing your date columns are `datetime` format:

```
from datetime import datetime
start_time = datetime(2020, 1, 1, 9, 30)
end_time = datetime(2020, 1, 1, 10, 30)

df['start_date'].dt.time.le(end_time.time())&df['end_date'].dt.time.ge(start_time.time())
```